# Getting <p> value from inside a div in Jsoup Not Working

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm currently trying to access a price value from the homedepot website.

URL: http://www.homedepot.ca/product/dewalt-heavy-duty-3-8-vsr-pistol-grip-drill-with-keyless-chuck/907316

the HTML with the price in it looks like this:

```
<div style="display: block;" id="regionalized-price"><p class="offer-price">$69.98</p></div>
```

I did some reading and I thought the following code should work:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.homedepot.ca/product/dewalt-heavy-duty-3-8-vsr-pistol-grip-drill-with-keyless-chuck/907316").get();

            Element content = doc.getElementById("regionalized-price");
            Elements p= content.getElementsByTag("p");


            System.out.println(p.text());
```

I've also just tried this to see if I could get a value come up:

```
Elements content2 = doc.getElementsByClass("offer-price");
            System.out.println(content2.text());
```

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if Home depot has something preventing my scrape from working.

Any suggestions or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the price by [CSS selector](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax):

```
Element price = doc.select("div#regionalized-price > p.offer-price").first();
System.out.println(price.text());
```

`div#regionalized-price > p.offer-price` means: give me the `p` tag with class `offer-price` that is right inside the `div` element with `id="regionalized-price"`.

---

But, the actual problem is that the price is loaded asynchronously via an [`XHR`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) request to http://www.homedepot.ca/async-fetch-regional-price?storeId=9999&pnList=907316 which returns an `XML`:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <mdata:Response xmlns:mdata="http://www.endeca.com/MDEX/data/IR600">
            <mdata:UntypedResult>
                <product-price partnumber="907316" reg-price="69.98"
                               promo-price="69.98" price-msg=""/>
            </mdata:UntypedResult>
        </mdata:Response>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

You would need to simulate this additional request and get the price from the `product-price` element.

Comment: I've just tried this and it seems to return a null value. Trying to debug through to see if I can figure out why. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the help. just to make sure I'm on track. I need to look up how to make a subrequest using jSoup?

Comment: @user818502 yup, to make it flexible, so that it would work for other items too, you would need first to extract `storeId` and `pnList` from the main item page, then use them as get parameters to get the price (see, the values after `?` in the subsequent url http://www.homedepot.ca/async-fetch-regional-price?storeId=9999&pnList=907316).